# How to define swagger docket bean in .xml file?

Tags: web-services, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, spring-rest

I done swagger integration from [this](https://indrabasak.wordpress.com/2016/04/07/swagger-2-integration-with-spring-rest/) link

It works ! But i want to configure docket bean in .xml file can i define docket bean in .xml file ? If yes then how to define docket bean and it properties..
Currently i'm doing the follwing way

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
        public Docket api() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(
               RequestH`enter code here`andlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
        }
    }
```

It would be appreciable if you will help me on this.

Thanks,
Sush

Comment: you might create this bean from xml file. try <bean ..... /> declaration in your xml after deleting @Configuration annotation.

Comment: yes you are right but how to define bean of above configuration class